# Application signature to fight hackers

Tags: android, android-security

I have a security question. 
Is it safe to send the app's signature as a String in a header to our backend server?
I mean am I exposing anything critical?

We are trying to fend off hackers and crackers who keep cracking our app with each update.

**EDIT:**
Here's some more info:
First, we obtain our release signature string and place it in our backend server. Then with each REST request the app makes, we retrieve the current signature from the packageManager and send the value in a header to the backend server. There a match check will take place between the current signature we retrieved and the one we saved in our backend server. If it succeeds the request returns ok, if it fails, we return an error.
We use HTTPs in all REST calls.

Comment: What hinders a hacker to send the same signature?

Comment: It depends a lot on your back end architecture and security model. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @Henry You are correct in assuming they can obtain the original signature and then use that in the header.  This is not an "air-tight" solution. It will work as long as they do not recognise this is actually being done :)
Obfuscating method names and headers might help in that. But yes, they can basically obtain the original signature and use it.

LawrenceChoy, well, all REST requests are done over HTTPS. We have an entire team dedicated to securing the backend server so I assume breaching that will be extremely hard. Is there anything specific I should ask them?

Comment: why do you need to send apps signature? It can create bigger problems if leaked like someone developing an app with same signature and access data from your app.

Comment: The idea is to match the app's original release signature with a signature that resides in our backend server. The matching will take place with each REST request the app makes. If a hacker changes the code some how, he needs to resign the app. This time the signature will be different though because the hacker does not have our key. So when we match the signatures now, they will not match, signalling the app may have been cracked. That's the idea any way... Obtaining the signature will only be possible via sniffing communications no? And we use HTTPs throughout.

Comment: @AlonMinski "Obtaining the signature will only be possible via sniffing communications" or by reverse engineering the original apk.

Comment: @Henry Are you certain reverse engineering the APK will also show the original release signature? I need to check this.

Comment: @AlonMinski see for example here: http://androidcracking.blogspot.co.at/2010/12/getting-apk-signature-outside-of.html

Comment: @Henry hmm. I see. So using this, you can retrieve the release signature of any app. Hmm. Alright thank you for this important information!